# Automatically determine the widths of ggplot facet labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I have an experimental design data I'm `ggplot`ting with `facet_grid`:

`factors` of the experimental design are:

```
factors <- c("mmm.control.30.2","mmm.control.60.2","mmm.control.150.2","mmm.control.300.2","mmm.control.1440.2",
"mmm.cxx.30.2","mmm.cxx.60.2","mmm.cxx.150.2","mmm.cxx.300.2","mmm.cxx.1440.2")
```

each `factor` has 3 replicates

```
samples <- unlist(lapply(factors,function(f) paste(f,1:3,sep="_")))
```

hence the `data.frame` is:

```
df <- data.frame(sample=samples,val=rnorm(30),stringsAsFactors = F)
df$replicate <- rep(1:3,10)
df$factor <- factor(gsub("_\\d$","",df$sample,perl=T),levels=factors)
```

this is a helper `function` for the plot

```
integerBreaks <- function(n = 5, ...)
{
  suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(scales))
  breaker <- pretty_breaks(n, ...)
  function(x){
    breaks <- breaker(x)
    breaks[breaks == floor(breaks)]
  }
}
```

I'm trying to `facet` the plot by factors using this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,aes(x=replicate,y=val,color=factor))+
  geom_point(size=3)+facet_grid(~factor,scales="free_x")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = integerBreaks())+
theme_minimal()+theme(legend.position="none",axis.title=element_text(size=8))
```

Which gives:
[image]

As you see both the `facet` labels and the left and right points in each `facet` get cut off because the ratio between the widths of the facet labels and the number of facets is large.

I know that I can play around with the `strip.text.x` `theme` parameter, but I'm wondering whether there's an automatic approach to get the labels to fit inside the facets (or space the facets further apart), and the points not get cut off.

I ask since this is somewhat of a generic code, where the number of facets and their labels change. It's probably possible to come up with a function for approximating the value of `strip.text.x` based on the number of facets and the widths of their labels but it sounds a bit tricky hence my curiosity if this has already been solved.

Comment: I split the facet title over 2 lines by adding `\n` in the names if they're too long. Would that be acceptable in your case?

Comment: I guess it's another option but it only seems to replace the option of playing around with the value of strip.text.x, which would still need a ratio between number of facets of the width of their labels to be figured out. I'm wondering if there's anything more generic than that.

Comment: Is this real or example data? The facets in your example are unnecessary, since you have one facet per variable. And I would not plot replicate as an axis variable. Looking at your sample names, they might be time points? If so I would plot value versus time and split by type (control or cxx). Can provide an example answer if that sounds helpful.

Comment: Hi @neilfws, I expanded this example to a case where faceting does make sense. Despite the sample names I'm not interested in plotting the samples versus a time axis.